# Extracting specific data from a file

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I have a particular csv file with the following data:

```
uid Business Area   employeeNumber  First   Name    Last Name   JobcodeID

EXBK145 Home Loans  9134805 Mason   Kapari  50635804
ABES623 Absa Consultants & Actuaries    9136459 Elroy   Shilling    50644965
EXTK194 Forex Operations    9140600 Tania   Kanniappen  60390922
ABNM539 Absa  Business Bank 9025659 Zodwa   Mgaga   60225348
ABAJ253 Absa Ins&Fin Advisers(Pty)Ltd   9040745 André   Joubert 50055313
ABSP391 Channel Sales & Service 9044366 Steph   Potgieter   4863
ABDL205 Absa Card   9083713 Lesego  Lekgoro 50050702
EXNM450 Channel Sales & Service 9121175 Thando  Shangase    60470761
EXSK201 Allpay  9130647 Sibusiso    Kambule 60615651
ABEK171 AIFA-PB Advisers    9011833 Esmé    Pretorius   60660026
```

I need to have the following output:

```
Action  uid       EmploymentStatus
modify  EXBK145   0
modify  ABES623   0
modify  EXTK194   0
modify  ABNM539   0
modify  ABAJ253   0
modify  ABSP391   0
modify  ABDL205   0
modify  EXNM450   0
modify  EXSK201   0
modify  ABEK171   0
```

from the input file all i need is the UID. Ive tried the "fast csv reader" but i doesn't work properly on my system........... I'm using visual C# 2010. I have also tries regular expressions but that didn't work as expected.

Any help will be appreciated and any examples so i can learn from this.

Thanks in advance
Kurt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have is a tab-delimited file. There are many free and open source libraries which can read them (for example, [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/quick_start.html)).

On the other hand, if you only need the first column, you can read the file line by line and parse it yourself using a [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx):

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TabDelimited.txt")) 
 {
      string line;
      // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
      // the file is reached.
      while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) 
      {
          int idx = line.IndexOf(' ');
          if (idx < 0)
             continue;

          // get the uid
          string uid = line.Substring(0, idx - 1);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the whole file using File.ReadAllLines(path) in a string array and then parse each line using the String.split(' ').

```
string [] strArray = File.ReadAllLines(path);
string [] line1 =strArray[0].Split(' ');
```

and line1 will have all the data of the first row.

Thanks
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

There is a good utility called CsvREader from LumentWorks. Its free. And it has good features.

Here's  a smaple code that i have used :

```
      CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(textreader, hasHeaders, delimiter);

      int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;
      string[] headers = null;
      if (m_bHasCSVHeaders)
        headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();     

      while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
      {...}
```

Hope it helps